# Как правильно обрабатывать Exception'ы контролов Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения, try-catch

У меня есть форма WinForms.
Все  данные сохраняются в БД на `SQL`, и форматы данных разный.Как обработать исключения(для каждого типа),что-бы было коротко для всех контролов(минимум 20-25 контролов) этой формы при нажатия на `Save Button`.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            BandivanKatDataContext db = new BandivanKatDataContext();
            Animals newAnimal = new Animals();
            newAnimal.number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            newAnimal.name = textBox2.Text;
            newAnimal.gender = textBox3.Text;
            newAnimal.age_Group = textBox4.Text;
            newAnimal.birthday = DateTime.Parse(textBox5.Text);
            newAnimal.breed = textBox7.Text;
            newAnimal.milk_volume = textBox6.Text;
            newAnimal.genetic = textBox17.Text;
            newAnimal.weghit = int.Parse(textBox18.Text);
            newAnimal.count_of_child = int.Parse(textBox19.Text);
            //
            db.Animals.InsertOnSubmit(newAnimal);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            //
            MotherAnimal newMotherAnimal = new MotherAnimal();
            newMotherAnimal.motherNumber = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
            newMotherAnimal.name = textBox9.Text;
            newMotherAnimal.birthday = DateTime.Parse(textBox10.Text);
            newMotherAnimal.genetic = textBox16.Text;
            newMotherAnimal.number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            //
            db.MotherAnimal.InsertOnSubmit(newMotherAnimal);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            //
            FatherAnimal newFatherAnimal = new FatherAnimal();
            newFatherAnimal.fatherNumber = int.Parse(textBox11.Text);
            newFatherAnimal.name = textBox12.Text;
            newFatherAnimal.birthday = DateTime.Parse(textBox13.Text);
            newFatherAnimal.genetic = textBox14.Text;
            newFatherAnimal.weghit = int.Parse(textBox15.Text);
            newFatherAnimal.number = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);

            db.FatherAnimal.InsertOnSubmit(newFatherAnimal);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            //
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Մուտքագրեք ճիշտ տվյալ");                
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: Это winforms или wpf? Если WPF, то почему не binding?

Comment: И ещё, почему работа с базой данных в UI-потоке? Это ж будет безбожно тормозить.

Comment: @VladD судя по EventArgs  - это WinForms

Comment: все написал через `Linq To Sql` не думаю что разница будет большой,база не так и уж большая

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, если Вы ищете как сделать правильно, то почему-то считаете, что сейчас делаете не правильно. Что конкретно Вас не устраивает?

Comment: @ixSci есть несколько `textbox`-и которые должны быть обязательно заполнени ,нужно вот это и еще во всех `textbox`-ах проверять введенное значения совпадает с типом данных или нет?и при возникновении ошибки ,в том`textbox`-е где была ошибка помечалась скажем красным цветом  и на ` MessageBox`-е  показал какая была ошибка?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Дайте всем контролам нормальные именования: например, если в `TextBox` заносится имя, то назовите его `textBoxName`, если заносится порода, назовите `textBoxBreed` и т. д. При этом будет легко читать и понимать код.
2. Используйте более подходящие контролы. Например, для ввода чисел - `NumericUpDown` - он автоматически не позволит ввести ничего, кроме чисел (можно настроить только на целые, можно на дробные). Для ввода дат используйте `DateTimePicker`, для ввода одного из известных значений (такие как пол) - `ComboBox` и т. д. При этом и пользователю будет легче и быстрее вводить данные, и от многих ошибок можно избавиться автоматически.
3. Для сигнализации пользователю об ошибках ввода можно использовать [ErrorProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.errorprovider%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).
4. Не ловите базовое исключение `Exception`. Ловите **конкретные** типы исключений. К сожалению, в MSDN документация по Linq2Sql весьма скудная. Список некоторых возможных исключений при выполнении `SubmitChanges` собран [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904317/5045688).
   Также ловите и обрабатывайте все исключения, могущие возникнуть при вызове методов `Parse` (но лучше использовать методы `TryParse`, а ещё лучше - соответствующие контролы типа `NumericUpDown`, `DateTimePicker`).
5. Почитайте про [AutoComplete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletesource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Его применение будет сильно помогать пользователям при вводе (и опять же избавит от ошибок).
6. Ну и на будущее освойте привязку данных - [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ef2xyb33%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Грамотное использование может сильно сократить код.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам стоит ограничить пользовательский ввод используя MaskedTextBox (параметры возможного ввода определяются фильтром). Для вывода сообщения о конкретной ошибке лучше использовать что-то подобное:

```
try 
{
// Здесь ваш код с возможными ошибками
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Во время выполнения программы возникла ошибка: " +     ex.Message);
}
```